# android gridview slow scrolling

Tags: android, gridview

I have an android activity with a gridview, each cell contains a textview with a single character (so there are around 60-70 characters/cells on the screen at a time). The scrolling of the gridview is unacceptably slow and unsmooth. I tried replacing the gridview with a listview, and the scrolling of the listview is much faster. How can i speed this up?

The activity layout is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/gridView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:columnWidth="56dp"
        android:numColumns="auto_fit" >
    </GridView>

</LinearLayout>
```

And inside each cell is this layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:textSize="40sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

And the code for the activity is:

```
public class TestGridActivity  extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.grid_activity);
        GridView gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView1);
        ArrayList<Map<String, String>> list = getData();
        SimpleAdapter arrayAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, list, 
            R.layout.grid_layout, new String[] { "literal"}, 
            new int[] { R.id.textView1});
        gridView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
    }
```

}

edit: pks asking to post adapter code, the above code I have used a generic simpleAdapter, but i have tried a custom view, which didn't help.

```
public class GridAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<Map<String, String>> list;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    public static class ViewHolder {
    TextView textView1;
    int position;
    }
    public GridAdapter(Context c, ArrayList<Map<String, String>> l) {
        context = c;
        list = l;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return list.size();
    }
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        if(convertView == null){
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_layout, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.textView1 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            holder.position = position;
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        holder.textView1.setText(list.get(position).get("character"));
        return convertView;
    }
}
```

I've also tried creating all the views in advance, and that didn't help scrolling speed.

Comment: Probably because you have many more cells on screen with a grid view.  When you scroll, its going to call getView on the adapter, which may not be cheap, once per cell for every few pixels of scroll.  That's a lot of processing.  And its probably not being as smart as it could be with the draw code either, as its so generic.

Comment: You should better post your adapter code, with `getView()` method so that I can probably tell you that how to use a customView and recycle older views. And by the way did you give a try to `gridView.setFastScrollEnabled(true);` has in case of listView.

Comment: Your adapter is good to go. Did you try `gridView.setFastScrollEnabled(true);`. Or you are doing some work on main UI thread .

Comment: I just tried `gridView.setFastScrollEnabled(true);` and that changed how the scrollbar works, allowing me to quickly change the grid position. But the problem is that the gridview isn't smooth. I'm not sure what you mean about the work on the main UI thread, the code I've posted is all i'm using at the moment.

Comment: If this the whole code then UI thread shouldn't be the causing issues as there is no dynamically coming images and textviews. Does the GC kicks in when you scroll through the Gridview.

Comment: No, but i do get the Choreographer saying "Skipped 30 frames! The application may be doing too much work on its main thread."

Comment: Look at the `public static class ViewHolder` make it private it shouldn't be public but this ain't the reason for calling of Choreographer. Apart from this, I would ignore that. The message you are seeing is important on phones but not in the emulator. The emulator is extremely slow.